# Mobile web interface for Google Calendar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, google-calendar-api

I'm writing an iPhone app in which I would like to display a public Google Calendar. I love their mobile interface for Calendar that is available when you log in, but I am wondering if there's a way to display this or a similar interface for public Google Calendars. Currently I'm displaying the desktop version of a public Calendar in a UIWebVIew, but it's hard to work with.

I realize that I could use the google APIs and write my own calendar implementation, but I'd prefer a mobile web interface due to the reduced complexity.

Answer (score 0):

just add a "/m"

to the url.

here is the google article:
http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=65923

Comment: This requires you to already be currently logged into a gmail account, which is unlikely for a webview

Comment: Is it a problem if you have to log in?